# Using static factory classes to generate GUI components - How and where to add the required listeners?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, listeners, factory-method

I would like to use factory classes and methods to generate GUI components, but I don't know how and in which class the various listeners should be declared and added to the components.

If I have a simple factory class such as that listed below should I add an ActionListener to the button before it is returned to the calling class. If the answer is "Yes" then how do I add the listener?

```
class GUIFactory
{
    public static JButton getJButton()
    {
        JButton aButton = new JButton();
        return aButton; 
    }
}
```

Suppose I wanted to use the getJButton() method to add 5 buttons to the GUI, how would I code the ActionListener so that it would know which button was clicked?

Or should the listeners be added in the calling class?

```
JFrame gui = new JFrame();
gui.add(AppFactory.getJButton());
```

I've tried the following

```
gui.add(GUIFactory.getJButton().addActionListener(new guiButtonListener()));
```

and got an error:

> *"void" type not allowed here.*

Comment: What is your intent in using a Factory? But if you want to use the factory you should consider to return the more common classes like `AbstractButton` from the method to be more flexible if your really changing the component being returned.

Comment: Also if you want to create your components leveraging method chaining, you might want to consider the *Builder Pattern*.

Comment: Hello Johannes. My intent is\was to create a modularised JFrame based GUI for my application. In the past my GUI's were allmost always constructed in one class and I wanted to get away from that to a more re-usable way of doing things. To be honest with you I have no experience whatsoever of implementing patterns, factories, etc - in fact the first I knew of them was here on SO when I was browsing java related questions. The code samples I posted were my first attempt based on other people's samples posted here here on SO.

Thanks for the Builder Pattern suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `addActionListener` returns void. Try:

```
JButton button = GUIFactory.getJButton();
button.addActionListener(new guiButtonListener())
gui.add(button);
```

Be aware that Swing GUI programming is quite idiomatic. Some may prefer using [Beans Binding](http://blogs.oracle.com/TechDaysEvents/entry/swing_application_framework_and_beans) (or other binding solution) to connect views and models with each other. One would argue that using an [Event Bus](http://www.eventbus.org/) yield the best, lowly coupled, highly reusable GUI components. Have a look also at [the Swing Application Framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/) (now deprecated, but the [BSAF](http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf) for is in very good condition) and [GUTS](http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Home) framework.

You'll see there are many attempts to address GUI programming and design issues. The topic is very broad, and solutions vary greatly.

Oh, and the big two Swing Rich Content Platforms ([NetBeans RCP](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html), [Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)) have very specific APIs to deal with GUIs. As an example, NetBeans RCP uses [Lookup](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/netbeans-lookups-explained), [Nodes](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html) and [Windows](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html) APIs to shield developer from Swing issues. The Eclipse team ditched Swing and wrote their own SWT GUI toolkit. You might want to look at tutorials if You'd wanted some great design references.

Comment: Eclipse RCP is not based upon Swing!

Comment: Hi there, Rekin. 
Thanks for the answer - I could've kicked myself when I saw your code sample :-) I have no experience of using factories so was just trying my hand based on other code samples I'd read here on SO Thanks.