# What would be considered good examples of implementing the builder pattern when used in the development of a GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, method-chaining, builder-pattern

I am a complete newbie when it comes to the use of factory classes and methods, patterns, etc - in fact I first learned of them here on Stackoverflow when browsing Java related questions :-)

In response to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543419/using-static-factory-classes-to-generate-gui-components-how-and-where-to-add-th) of mine it was suggested that I look into the use of the Builder Pattern in the development of my GUI's and so I am seeking good easily understood examples demonstrating how an application's user interface could be put toghether using this pattern and method-chaining, etc.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joshua Bloch's [*Item 2: Consider a builder*](http://www.ddj.com/java/208403883?pgno=2) is always a good place to start. Regarding GUI development, many layout managers use the builder pattern. [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a good introduction.

Comment: Thanks trashgod, I've up voted and accepted this as the answer due to the excellent Dr.Dobbs article.

Comment: BTW, Item 2 is excerpted from Joshua Bloch's _Effective Java_, 2nd ed. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/

Answer (score 6):

There are probably other (and better) examples but here is one.

When working with `GridBagConstraints`, one could use this horrible constructor:

```
public GridBagConstraints(int gridx, int gridy,
                          int gridwidth, int gridheight,
                          double weightx, double weighty,
                          int anchor, int fill,
                          Insets insets, int ipadx, int ipady)
```

But I consider it unusable. And people most often end up using the empty constructor and setting the various public attributes to override the defaults values.

As an alternative, one could use a builder, something like this:

```
somePanel.add(
    getContent(),
    new ConstraintsBuilder()
        .gridLocation(1, 1)
        .gridSize(1, 1)
        .weight(0.0, 0.0)
        .anchor(NORTHWEST)
        .build() );
```

Just an example.

Comment: One sees something similar in NetBeans' GUI editor with `GroupLayout`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561540

Comment: Cay Horstmann has a great example of a GBC builder like this too... http://www.horstmann.com/articles/GBC.java

Answer (score 3):

I think "[Source Making](http://sourcemaking.com/)" does a nice job of introducing design patterns (as well as UML, Antipatterns and Refactoring). You may want to check the site out.

You can read about the Builder here: [Source Making: Builder Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder)

Comment: I initially dismissed this, but the builder discussion includes nice _before_ and _after_ examples in several languages: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder

Comment: +1 The source making book is IMHO much more enjoyable to read than the GoF book.

Answer (score 2):

Here is good BuilderPattern example related to building UI. (There is not explanation but easy to understand if you know Builder Pattern)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/BuilderPatternExample.htm

Builder Pattern more information :

http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/builder_pattern.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/BuilderPatterninJava.htm